# How do you exit uTorrent "Unlock Now" screen?

Tags: utorrent

I am using uTorrent 3.2 (build 27636). I would like to ask if somebody has encountered the uTorrent "Unlock Now" screen and how to exit it. I have not tested this on other versions but this is how you open the "Unlock Now" screen:

[image: SU533225 example]

First, make sure that Show Status Bar and Show Detailed Info are checked in Options. Then hover near the [encircled area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLGLR.png) (somewhere around the Files and Info tabs). If the cursor changes to the one which indicates clickable links, click it. One thing I noticed is there might be a small random offset since the clickable area changes but still stays within the encircled range. I am also not sure if other versions have other clickable areas. Once you click it, the annoying ["Unlock Now"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IffJw.png) page will open:

[image: SU533225 second example]

As of now, what I do to go back to normal view is to close the program and restart it, which can be quite a hassle if you have many downloads and seeds. Is there any other way to go back to normal view with exiting the program? Or which version does not have this feature?

Comment: Never used that version, but looking at what it offers... Seem like legit garbage... Just saying

Comment: @pnuts I feel it's quite scammy, simply because it's uninvited, and the OP has issues getting rid of it. As well, on my uTorrent, I don't see that page anywhere (although I run OSX)

Comment: @pnuts I haven't been able to see that "trigger" either, but I did happen to get stuck on that screen somehow, once. I didn't understand how. Looks like a little bug.

Comment: also applies to 3.4 "Upgrade" screen,  which is the same only different :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The last time I got stuck on that screen, the way I found to get out was to show the sidebar (Options, or press F7) and click "Torrents." Yeah, it's well hidden.

Yes, I was also "whaaaaa" when it happened, especially since for me, exiting and launching again did not solve it!

Comment: Also, if you do show sidebar and can't click on torrents - maximize your uTorrent window and you'll see it. If there's not much space in the window, only thing you can click on is "upgrade to uTorrent Pro" part...

Answer (score 1):

Those instructions don't seem to work with 3.3. Here's how I fixed it:

- Hit F7 to make sure you're showing the side bar.
- Click Help->Show Get Started Page.
- Now click Torrents in the side bar. This may work for you, but for me all it did was show the lower pane (with individual torrent information) but the top pane was still "get started".
- In the Get Started pane, click "Never show this again" (or whatever it's called) in the top right.
- Restart uTorrent